# $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+, \dfrac{a}{a+7b}+\dfrac{b}{b+7c}+\dfrac{c}{c+7a} \geq \dfrac{3}{8}$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof

How to prove
$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$
$$\dfrac{a}{a+7b}+\dfrac{b}{b+7c}+\dfrac{c}{c+7a} \geq \dfrac{3}{8}$$

my solution 
this equivalent to
$$\dfrac{7(13a^2b+13b^2c+13c^2a+35a^2b^2+35b^2c^2+35b^2c^2-144abc)}{8(a+7b)(b+7c)(c+7a)} \geq 0$$
from AM-GM, we can get 
$$13a^2b+13b^2c+13c^2a \geq 39abc$$
$$35b^2c^2+35b^2c^2+35b^2c^2 \geq 105abc$$
done
I want to know better way to prove this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $\frac{a}{7a+b}+\frac{b}{7b+c}+\frac{c}{7c+a}\le\frac38$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483200/how-to-prove-fraca7ab-fracb7bc-fracc7ca-le-frac38)

Comment: It seems bit different from my one, but it is also interesting! Thanks

Comment: having regard to the comment of   
Sourav Ghosh: $\frac{a}{a+7b}+\frac{b}{b+7c}+\frac{c}{c+7a}=3-7[\frac{b}{a+7b}+\frac{c}{b+7c}+\frac{a}{c+7a}]\geq 3-7\frac{3}{8}=\frac{3}{8}$

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct.

Let $A$ be your expression and $B=a(a+7b) + b(b+7c) +c(c+7a)$. Then it is enought, by Cauchy Shwarz inequality, to prove $$8(a+b+c)^2\geq 3(a^2+b^2+c^2+7ab+7bc+7ca)$$
i.e.
$$5(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq 5(ab+bc+ca)$$ which is true by again CS or AG.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what is AG. You mean AM-GM inequaltiy?

Comment: Yes..................

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Better way is always calculus but you may need Wolfram Alpha if you are not into solving equations.

Let $\frac{b}{a}=x$ and $\frac{c}{b}=y$. We want to maximize the function
$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+7x}+\frac{1}{1+7y}+\frac{xy}{xy+7}$ in the open first quadrant of the cartesian plane.

Solving $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$, I think, we get $(x,y)=(49,\frac{1}{2041}), (\frac{1}{2041},49)$ or $(1,1)$.

$(1,1)$ will do the minimum.